# Chartjs on Reactjs - beginAtZero not working

Tags: reactjs, charts, chart.js

I have been trying to make this bar chart start from 0, but it doesn't always work - the weird part is that sometimes it works - it begins from 0, but when I refresh the page it begins from some random number or sometimes even from the number on the lowest bar in the bar chart. I added the min:0 hoping this would fix it. I can't get a hold of the issue, what am I doing wrong?

```
 const data = {
 labels: ["Red", "Blue"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: chartData,
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
      }
const options = {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true,
                                    min:0
                }
            }]
        }
    }

const chartData = [shownTotal, shownNewTotal];



 <Chart chartData={data} options={options} key={key}  legendPosition="bottom"/>
```

EDIT: I forgot to add the options code the first time I posted this.